# List of android application categories and permissions

Tags: android, android-manifest

Just wondering, is there a list anywhere on the internet that has a list of all the permissions that are generally associated with certain application category types?

eg.

```
Media Applications generally have the following permissions:
android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER
android.permission.ASEC_ACCESS
android.permission.ASEC_CREATE
android.permission.ASEC_DESTROY
android.permission.ASEC_MOUNT_UNMOUNT
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM
```

Thanks

Comment: From the permissions you have listed it looks like you are looking at `system` / `signature` permissions. This list is hard to find! http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Better yet https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 3):

I think there is some confusion because the manifest is very clear to developers which permissions are required. However, when installing users are presented with categories of permssions rather than the complete list of individual permissions. I agree, a complete mapping of individual permissions to permission categories would be very helpful. Here are the categories one example application requires on install:

[image]

I found this resource which is helpful, but does not explain everything. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html explains that a developer can run the following command to display “permissions in a form roughly similar to how the user will see them”.

**adb shell pm list permissions -s**

> All Permissions:
>
> Development tools: send Linux signals to applications, make all
>   background appli cations close, limit number of running processes,
>   enable application debugging
>
> Your personal information: write Browser's history and bookmarks, read
>   Browser's  history and bookmarks, read contact data, add or modify
>   calendar events and sen d email to guests, write to user defined
>   dictionary, read owner data, read user defined dictionary, write
>   contact data, choose widgets, read calendar events, wr ite owner data
>
> Services that cost you money: send SMS messages, directly call phone
>   numbers
>
> Your location: mock location sources for testing, access extra
>   location provider  commands, coarse (network-based) location, fine
>   (GPS) location
>
> Your messages: Exchanges messages and receives sync notifications from
>   Google se rvers, send WAP-PUSH-received broadcast, edit SMS or MMS,
>   read instant messages,  receive WAP, write instant messages, send
>   SMS-received broadcast, read SMS or M MS, Read Email attachments,
>   receive SMS, receive MMS
>
> Network communication: view network state, Broadcast data messages to
>   applicatio ns., Send heartbeat to Google Talk server, Broadcast data
>   messages to applicatio ns., Market license check, create Bluetooth
>   connections, view Wi-Fi state, Allow s the application to accept cloud
>   to device messages from application's service,  full Internet access
>
> Your accounts: Android services, Orkut, act as an account
>   authenticator, Google App Engine, Picasa Web Albums, view configured
>   accounts, Google Spreadsheets, Go ogle Notebook, Google Checkout
>   accounts, Google Groups, discover known accounts,  act as the
>   AccountManagerService, Knol, Blogger, Google Checkout QA accounts, G
>   oogle Health, Google Checkout Sandbox accounts, Google Docs, Google
>   Book Search,  Google News, Android services, iGoogle accounts, Google
>   Talk, YouTube, manage t he accounts list, JotSpot, Dodgeball, access
>   other Google services, Google Voice , AdWords, YouTube usernames, use
>   the authentication credentials of an account, Google mail, AdSense,
>   Google Webmaster Tools, Google Maps, access all Google ser vices,
>   contacts data in Google accounts, Google WiFi, Google Calendar, Google
>   mo bile applications, Google Base, Google Finance
>
> Storage: modify/delete SD card contents
>
> Phone calls: modify phone state, intercept outgoing calls, read phone
>   state and identity
>
> Hardware controls: take pictures, control flashlight, test hardware,
>   record audi o, change your audio settings, control vibrator
>
> System tools: allow Wi-Fi Multicast reception, delete all application
>   cache data , get information on secure storage, change background data
>   usage setting, force  stop other applications, uninstall shortcuts,
>   disable keylock, read sync statis tics

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this list has all the permissions but it does have a lot of permissions not found in the Android Developer reference.