# Categorize Permission of Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I want to categorize all the permissions of android into the following categories :

1. Track Location
2. Access Messages and Contacts
3. Access Accounts
4. Services That Cost Money
5. Development Tools
6. Hardware Controls
7. Access Network
8. Access Personal Information
9. Phone Calls
10. Storage
11. System Tools

**How do i classify all the permissions ?
Any clue or links available ?**

Comment: What do you mean you want to categorize them? Like on the play store?

Comment: Read the permission details and assign it to the one you think most suited http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by your question:

1)
If you want to categorize all possible permission by yourself, please do so: [reference link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

2)
If you want to learn about all categories that could be presented to the end user, please [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7531622/1110688) and [this Android developer link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html).